# Lipschitz constant of a Matrix Valued Function

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Consider the function $H(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(w^T x_i) x_i x_i^T $, where $w\in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\forall i$: $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$. Further, know $|f'(y)| \leq 1$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Note, $d > n$ is possible.

What is the Lipschitz constant for this function, i.e. for which $M$ the following inequality is true?

$\|H(w) - H(w') \|_{op,2} \leq M \|w- w'\|_2$ for all $w,w'\in \mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: An estimate is easy to make, I doubt that there is a clean exact value without additional assumptions?

Comment: I am not looking for an exact tight value here and will be satisfied with non-trivial estimates. However, what kind of additional assumptions do you need for a clean value?

Comment: Do you know that $|f'(y)| \le 1$ or just $f'(y) \le 1$?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $|f'(x)| \le 1$, then you can quickly obtain the following estimate
using the mean value theorem.

$H(w)-H(w') = \sum_i (f(x_i^T w)-f(x_i^Tw')) x_i x_i^T$, hence
$\|H(w)-H(w')\| \le  \sum_i |x_i^T (w-w')| \| x_i x_i^T\| $, and
so $L=\sum_i \|x_i\|^3$ is one estimate.

Comment: The bound $|f'(x)< 1|$ is alright. However, the above estimate will result in M = O(n),  which is not quite satisfactory. Is there any way to bound it in terms of the spectral radius of $\sum_i x_i x_i^T$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an $O(n)$ bound.

Comment: I mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|x_i\|^3 = O(n)$.

Comment: I still really don't understand what you mean. The norm of $\sum_k x_k x_k^T$ could be $\ge Kn$ for some positive $K$.

Comment: I see your point. I think it was my mistake. I will check how the bounds translate in my setting. To be really precise, I am interested in bounding M using the eigenvalues of the matrix $\sum_i x_ix_i^T$ and maybe $\max_i \|x_i\|$. Indeed, the eigenvalue can be large.